# Document Library/Permissions/Search - Help!

Tags: document-library, search, permissions, document

I have a SharePoint Library with just over 800 documents. Only 5 teams have access to the library. Requirements are below;

1. Create different views for each team so that a team can only see documents related to members of that team - Done
2. Allow search in the document library - Done
3. Search results should only display documents that users are allowed see (as set in views) - Problem

Can someone please help with this issue? requirements 1 & 2 have been completed and currently when users search for documents, the search could also return documents that they should not see. How can i prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

Would you like to give us more information about your actual implementation?

I hope you did not use audiences to achieve this, because this will not work for your requirements.

If each document can be accessed by one team only, I would do the following:

1. Create 5 folders (one for each team)
2. For each folder give access to the corresponding team
3. Create your views making sure that the folders are also not displayed (of you do nto wish to see these five folders)

This will make sure the search engine works correctly.

If, in your case, some documents must be accessed by more than one team, my solution will not work.

Comment: Thanks a lot Yandr. I actually used audience when creating links for each team which works perfectly fine. The only issue now is that when users can search for any document within the document library even. 

Also, in some cases, documents must be accessible by more than 1 team. so i guess, as you've mentioned above, the folder solution will not work. Any other thoughts on this?